# Apache Camel, how to perform asynchronous messaging inside the route

Tags: apache-camel, jms, cxf, message-queue, microservices

I want to make Camel route, where client calls synchronous SOAP service. Route will transform the request to asynchronous message, which is sent to message queue MQ2. Route waits until there is correlated reply message in it's own message queue MQ1. Finally route sends reply to client.

How do I

1. Include the *asynchronous* request/reply phase inside the route handling synchronous WS invocation
2. Implement this using *different* message queue instances, retaining the correlation between incoming messages and original requests
3. Optimize the performance to free the resources while waiting, if possible
4. Ensure that I'm able to run multiple instances of each service+MQ bundle

Basically I have chain of three services, each of with it's own one-way message queue bundled in the service. Last service in the chain must return the final result back to first service, **and only to the first service**, because the result can't be meditated to preceding service instances (or their message queues).

Also, it's an opinion to implement this with one-way SOAP services with callback meshanism, if that is easier with Camel. The point is, the synchronous invocation must be converted to asynchronous chain of operations, and joined back to synchronous. It is vital that first service may be aware of only the final result, and also intermediate services are forbidden to obtain the result produced by the services later in the chain.

Or is there at least an EIP pattern defined for this specific problem to get me on the right tracks?

[image]

Here is an example of the route I have so far: it just sends the message into MQ2.

```
    <route id="cxfToJMSRoute">
        <from uri="cxf:bean:endpoint" />
        <convertBodyTo type="String"/>
        <to uri="activemq:queue:api" />
        <!-- How to wait for the correlated reply in different MQ? -->
        <!-- Releasing resource while waiting, if possible -->
        <!-- And finally intercept and return the result -->
        <!-- And do all this with horizontal scalability in mind -->
        <!-- Considering all exceptions like network failures in any segement -->
    </route>
```